# Audio recognition and fingerprint using sklean & librosa

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to create a model that can predict who has speak with different word.

In this case i try to use feature

```
Mfcc
Melspectogram
Tempo
Chroma stft
Spectral Centroid
Spectral Bandwidth
Tempo
```

And for train that i am use `RandomforestRegressor`

It's possible to create model like that?

Comment: Please read the [description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ml/info) of the ML tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sound processing and feature extraction part, `librosa` is definitely going to provide you all you need.

For the machine learning part however, speaker identification (also called "voice recognition") is a relatively complex task. You probably will get more success using techniques from deep learning. You can certainly try to use random forests if you like, but you'll probably get a lower accuracy and will have to spend more time doing feature engineering. In fact, it will be a good exercise for you to compare the results you can get with the various techniques.

For an example tutorial on speaker identification using Keras, see e.g. [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-build-a-neural-network-for-voice-classification-5e2810fe1efa).